# 22.04 - ufw/ip tables could not fetch rule set

Tags: server, 22.04, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm trying to get UFW up and running on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu server 22.04. But I am at a loss.

```shell
# via SSH session:
~$ sudo ufw status
ERROR: problem running iptables: iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Invalid argument

# On screen connected to RPi:
[...] Module has invalid ELF structures
```

Did an update and restart, but that did nothing.
Had a search and tried using `iptables-legacy`, which did still not work... Tried blacklisting the legacy modules and using iptables-nft.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Try using below command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```